# Pre-paid data SIM for voip in Egypt

Tags: cellphones, data-plans, egypt

I'll travel to Egypt (Sharm el Sheik airport and then to Taba) in two weeks. I am looking for a Prepaid Data SIM for **VoIP calls**? For me, I think, 1GB is enough for 15 days.

I have checked Vodafone and [Etisalat](http://www.etisalat.eg/etisalat/portal/mobile_internet_en) but I'm not sure what I need. I mean I know that from there the *Regular - Connect 25* is OK with me. How can I get this service, what do I need to buy exactly and where?

Is there a card what I can purchase from a shop without any contract like LIDL or TESCO SIMs in Europe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: At Sharm el Sheikh airport you can find a Vodafone kiosk near the exit. The guy who was there was very helpful. For 10 USD I got 1 GB data and some minutes of call within 5 minutes.

All my VoIP apps (Viber, Skype, Internet Call) are working if I have coverage.

Answer (score 2):

Using Mobile Phone or 3G Model will not allow you to have any VoIP call unless you have VPN. I personally can't use Skype on Etisalat or Vodafone for VoIP calls. Whatsapp calls also doesn't work.
Egyptian Regulatory [confirmed](https://www.telegeography.com/products/commsupdate/articles/2010/03/17/ntra-confirms-skype-ban-on-mobile-internet-connections/) that and [another source](http://egyptianstreets.com/2015/10/07/social-media-users-enraged-over-alleged-skype-viber-whatsapp-ban-in-egypt/) mention viber